# Nim game - specify winner

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *@author Andy 
 *@verison 21.11.2012
 */
public class NimGame
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println ("**********      Hello Welcome to the game Nim           *********");
    System.out.println ("               The game is relatively simple....        ");
    System.out.println ("               This is a game for two players.          "); 
    System.out.println ("            There is a heap containing 10 to 20 stones.");
    System.out.println ("           Players take turns to remove 1-4 stones     "); 
    System.out.println ("           The player who removes the last stone wins. ");
    System.out.println ("******************************************************************");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int heapSize = 15;
    int stones = 0;
    boolean nextInteger = false;
    boolean lessThanFour = false;
    String player1 = "Player 1";
    String player2 = "Player 2";
    String player = player1;

    System.out.println ("The number of stones currently in the heap is :- " + heapSize);
    System.out.println();

    while (heapSize > 0)
    {

        nextInteger = false;
        lessThanFour = false;
        System.out.println (player + ":" + "how many stones will you take from the heap?");
        System.out.println();
        while (nextInteger == false && lessThanFour == false)
        {

            if (scan.hasNextInt())
            {
                nextInteger = true;
                stones = scan.nextInt();

                if (stones <=4 && stones >0)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println ("You picked " + stones);
                    heapSize = (heapSize - stones);
                    if (heapSize >= 0)
                    {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println ("There are " + heapSize + "stones left");  
                    System.out.println();
                    lessThanFour = true;
                    System.out.println();
                    if (player.equals(player1))
                    {
                        player = player2;
                    }
                    else

                    {
                        player = player1;
                    }



                }

                else 

                {
                    System.out.println ("Bad input, please try again");
                    nextInteger = false;
                    scan.nextLine();
                }
            }

            else 

            {
                System.out.println ("Bad input, please try again");
                scan.nextLine();
            }


        }
    }
}
}
}
```

I dunno how to implement a way to specify player 1 or player 2 being the winner once the sizeheap (number of stones left) reaches 0. Any help would be appreciated. Also when the sizeheap reaches a negative number, it will display 'bad input' but then any other number inserted after that also displays 'bad input.'

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for SSCCE, nice work.

Comment: @Steve are you sure that OP is really doing SSCCE? I bet he is simply throwing his whole source code and asking for debug...

Comment: Well, it compiles, and it's easy to work with, that's better than most so I won't complain ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just need to rewrite `if (heapSize >= 0)` so it displays a win message:

`if (heapSize > 0) {...} else { ...win... }`

Here's the critical part, fixed, streamlined a bit, and edited:

```
if (stones <= 4 && stones > 0) {
    System.out.println ("\nYou picked " + stones);
    heapSize = (heapSize - stones);

    if (heapSize > 0) {
        System.out.println ("\nThere are " + heapSize + " stones left\n\n");  

        // Could use a ternary operator here:
        // player = (player.equals(player1) ? player2 : player1);

        if (player.equals(player1)) {
            player = player2;
        }
        else {
            player = player1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (player.equals(player1)) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
        }       
    }
}
```

Further tips:

- You can just use a newline `\n` instead of an `System.out.println()`.
- The `lessThanFour` flag is probably unnecessary

Comment: No problem, happy coding.  That's a pretty entertaining game!